# Android App - Submission to play store

Tags: android

I made android app and tested it, posted to play store successfully.
But the problem is that its available only on play store with sprint service provider only. Its not visible on TMobile android phone's playstore.
Am I missing something in play store or application settings?
Here's the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.conscience.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
        android:name="com.conscience.lite.ConscienceApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.lite.home.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.album.AlbumActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_album" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.VideoSaveActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_save" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.EditVideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_edit" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.settings.FaqActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_faq" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.settings.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.settings.BGSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bgsettings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.settings.VideoServicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_services" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.cal.CalenderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calender" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conscience.app.AddNewVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="VideoPlayer"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: For now, paste the `AndroidManifest` (just in case). Then see if there aren't any options which you set during the upload. After that, tell us the actual application, so we can see if it's available on our devices. Do you know if T-Mobile uses their separate PlayStore application or something?

Comment: I added the manifest file. The app name is "ConscienceLite". Dont know if its a different playstore on t-mobile, the app is pushed to google play store only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google do provide a custom Play Store front end to network providers, for example here in the UK the o2 network take use of it to show o2's list of suggested apps and their own branded apps.

It is possible that the tmobile store was still being updated. Google push apps out to servers in a round robin style, rather than all at once. I have checked and your app is appearing in the store (both generic and o2 specific) here in the UK.

Comment: is it possible to download apps from google play store on mobiles that use o2 network?

Comment: Yep, fully possible. They simply add a few screens to the native play store application (example https://www.dropbox.com/sc/fvows8cyd43sj1l/pyZHB9Cj5r). Otherwise the app store is the same as the standard Google Play Store. Have you rechecked the tmobile store recently to see if your app has appeared?

Comment: i dont know anything about tmobile store. i've to check

Answer (score -2):

Just update manifest with this then publish your apps... it will work....

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  />
```